# Render strongly type partial view in layout MVC4 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model, partial-views, strongly-typed-view

I have some issues with rendering strongly type partial view in layout view.

1. partial view (menu) is band with model Menu
2. this partial view I want to render in _layout.chtml, so it 'll be avliable in all views.

I want to make avalible the partial view(menu) in all pages/view. the problem I face is where to put the action for partial view to populate it from DB on page load.

thanks

```
---------------------- My code is--------------------
partial view inside shared folder.
@model List<Menu>
@foreach(var item in Model){// here is the html/model item inside to display}
--------------------------------------
HomeView.chtml inside home folder

@model List<homemodel>
.... here goes html code/ plus homemodel loop/data etc.
------------------------------
HomeController{
public ActionResult HomeView()
{
.........return view();
}
public PartialViewResult partialmenu()
{
// data from db
return partialview(partialobject as list);
}

------------------------
layoutview.chtml

--html code---
{@ Html.renderpartial("partialview");}
.. html code...
```

Answer (score 0):

`I want to make available the partial view(menu) in all pages/view. the problem I face is where to put the action for partial view to populate it from DB on page load.`

Write in layout: `Html.RenderAction('MyMenu')` OR `Html.Action('MyMenu')` and then populate it from any source. Your action will return strongly typed model.

Comment: @user2315795 Replace `RenderPartial` with `RenderAction`. You can't use `RenderPartial`, because you must provide model to it.

Answer (score 0):

> where to put the action for partial view to populate it from DB on
>   page load.

every view has it's own controller..regardless if it is partial or not...therefore you could populate your *view* on it's own controller...